# Excel VBA - Add or Reduce Amount in cell from cell reference

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to look for some VBA Code that can reduce the Quantity in stock whenever there is Item issued in Invoice. For Example if "Keyboard" and "Mouse" item issued by 2 and 3 then the number should automatically reduce in in Stock "Quantity" Column for respected item

I already search for the solution and couldn't get one. Hope you guys can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can decrement the value of a cell in VBA: `ActiveCell.value = ActiveCell.value - 1`. So, in theory, it would be possible loop though all the records in your list of invoices and deduct that from your inventory list. It sounds like you're taking the first steps towards rolling your own Excel-based MRP - and so it might be worth considering alternatives (e.g. https://www.odoo.com/, http://ofbiz.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could add some more information about where the values are, and how your invoice event is called it would help.

Are you running this through a Form? or on a worksheet?  If there are textBoxes with information, just use those when you declare your input variables below.

Anyway.  This could easily be condensed, but I'm laying it out in a more informative way so you can learn the concepts behind it instead of the most concise code.

EDITED WITH REVISED CODE: After Comments with details.  SEE PIC

```
Sub InventoryUpdate()

Dim qtyIn As Integer
Dim qtySold As Integer
Dim sheeteName As String
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim lastStockRow As Integer
Dim lastInvoiceRow As Integer
Dim tProduct As String
Dim sRow As Integer


'Declare the sheetName here once, so you don't have to replace it every time it changes
sheetName = "Sheet1"

'Determine the last rows, unless you know it already, then ignore this.
lastInvoiceRow = Sheets(sheetName).Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
lastStockRow = Sheets(sheetName).Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row

'Loop through the rows of your table. Since you know the range, it's rows 4-10
For iRow = 4 To lastInvoiceRow
    'Set the temp Product name as row, Column B, and the Qty Sold from Column C
    tProduct = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(iRow, 2)
    qtySold = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(iRow, 3)

    For sRow = 4 To lastStockRow
        If Sheets(sheetName).Cells(sRow, 5) = tProduct Then
            qtyIn = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(sRow, 6)
            Sheets(sheetName).Cells(sRow, 6) = qtyIn - qtySold
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sRow

Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and concept. To be more precise please follow the link: [Sample](http://goo.gl/vXgEKT) to view my sample spreadsheet image based on my question.

Comment: OK. That would involve a quick loop.  I'll adjust the code above.

Comment: Thank you, It was helpful. If you don't mind can I ask more question. How about if stock in item list sorted differently like "Keyboard" in Invoice list is at row 4 and the "keyboard" in Stock list at row 8, I mean the Item is not on the same row. How to make it search the same item in stock list and reduce the quantity?

Comment: That would be a bit different.   Assuming you've got the Stock list on Column F like in the example, you'd want to get the last row of the stock. Grab the Product Type in a variable.  then run through the list on the right and check for matches.  When you find it, continue through the loop.
Check the code above.